# SignerID cast to X509CertSelector in BouncyCastle library

Tags: java, security, x509certificate, bouncycastle, x509

I'm trying to verify if an specific message is signed with a valid signature from an entity certificate recognized by my own trust anchor. I'm doing this:

```
public static boolean isValid(CMSSignedData signedData, X509Certificate rootCert) throws Exception
{
    CertStore certsAndCRLs = signedData.getCertificatesAndCRLs("Collection", "BC");
    SignerInformationStore signers = signedData.getSignerInfos();
    Iterator it = signers.getSigners().iterator();

    if (it.hasNext()){
        SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation)it.next();

        X509CertSelector signerConstraints = signer.getSID();

        PKIXCertPathBuilderResult result = buildPath(rootCert, signerID, certsAndCRLs);

        return signer.verify(result.getPublicKey(), "BC");
    }
    return false;
}
```

But this line is giving me a compile error:

```
X509CertSelector signerConstraints = signer.getSID();
```

Because it is unable to cast from SignerId to X509CertSelector. I tried using explicit cast:

```
X509CertSelector signerConstraints = (CertSelector) signer.getSID();
```

And:

```
X509CertSelector signerConstraints = (X509CertSelector) signer.getSID();
```

Without results. How can I do this? Thanks

PS: notice that this code is extracted from "Beginning Cryptography with Java" by David Hook, but it doesn't compile.

Comment: Could you give us the API version of Bouncy Castle? And the answer you will certainly get from Dave when he's doing his rounds on the BC mailing list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved yesterday my own problem. I think that was something
relative to .jar included as external archive to my project. Now, I'm using
these:

```
bcprov-jdk16-145.jar
bcmail-jdk16-145.jar
```

Instead of:

```
bcprov-jdk15on-147.jar
bcmail-jdk15on-147.jar
```

Maybe the old versions didn't support this kind of implicit cast.

**EDIT**: David Hook's answer in http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-SignerID-and-X509CertSelector-td4620461.html

> Use org.bouncycastle.cert.selector.jcajce.JcaX509CertSelectorConverter
>   - unfortunately the code in "Beginning Cryptography With Java" is now getting out of date. Guess I'll have to get the word processor out
>   again.
>
> Regards,
>
> David

Comment: Fran, the -145 ones are actually lower versions than the -147 versions. The 16 and 15 are only relating to the non-commercial version number of the Java runtime. So this answer may be correct now, but would mean you won't be able to upgrade. Please post then answer of David instead.

Comment: @owlstead This is actually to do some homework for a subject from my master, so I can do it without future maintenance thoughts. Anyways, I'll edit my own answer to provide you David's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using BouncyCastle bcmail-jdk15on 1.52 I succeeded to do this using :

```
X509CertificateHolderSelector x509CertificateHolderSelector = new X509CertificateHolderSelector(info.getSID().getSubjectKeyIdentifier());
X509CertSelector certSelector = new JcaX509CertSelectorConverter().getCertSelector(x509CertificateHolderSelector);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Collection<X509Certificate> certCollection = (Collection<X509Certificate>) certs.getCertificates(certSelector);
```